# understand head and pointers for a singly-linked list

Tags: python, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

Maybe this is a rather basic question, but I have seem this quite a lot on leetcode.

For example, one provides me a head of a singly linked list, than I define a pointer variable say:

```
curr = head
```

After I revert the head:

```py
def revert(head):     
    prev, curr = None, head 

    while curr: 
        nxt = curr.next 

        curr.next = prev 
        prev = curr 

        curr = nxt 

    return prev
```

Now I would obtain a singly linked list, in which case the order is reversed and prev is the head of it.

When the loop completes, of course the curr pointer points to `None`, I am wondering why the head gets modified to only include the last element.

And a more generic question is that, how come does the head gets updated automatically once the pointer is changed? Is this something that is achieved by the leetcode backend or something that is aware from a data structure perspective.

Comment: Will you show how you call this `revert()` function? How do you assing `head`?

Answer (score 1):

> how come does the head gets updated automatically once the pointer is changed?

The short answer is that it doesn't get updated automatically.

In your example, the variable `head` points to a mutable object, meaning that modifications to it happen in place even when done from a function scope.

A regular python `list` is also mutable, to demonstrate let's take a regular python list and make some modifications to the contents.

```
def change_last_index(example):
    lst = example  # lst and example both point to the same mutable object
    lst[-1] = 153

example = [1, 2, 3]
change_last_index(example)

print(example) # [1, 2, 153]
```

It's the same concept with the links/nodes of the linked list.

---

Lets create an example `Node`  class/data structure that works with your function.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None
    def __repr__(self): 
        return f"{self.val} -> {self.next}"
```

And to demonstrate it's mutability we can create a function that creates a new node and assigns it to it's next attribute.

```
def set_next_node(node, value):
    node1 = node  #  node1, node, and head all point to same object
    node1.next = Node(value)  # create new node and assign to head.next
    
head = Node(0)
print(head)               # output:  0 -> None

set_next_node(head, 1)
# the function will create a new node with value of 1 set it to `head.next`

print(head)               # output:  0 -> 1 -> None
```

---

In your `revert` function on the first line...

```
prev, curr = None, head
```

... the `curr` variable now points to the same object that the `head` points. So on the very first iteration of the `while` loop, `head.next` gets changed to `None` when the line `curr.next = prev` gets executed.

Then on the second iteration the very same line assigns `head` to the `next` attribute of a different node because `prev` gets reasigned to the `head` object when the line `prev = curr` gets executed.

Here is an example you can run using your `revert` function and the example `Node` class from above.  I suggest running it and all the above code in an IDE/debugger so you can track the changes step by step, and run your own experiments, like making the linked list longer or changing the node values to strings.

```
head = Node(0)
head.next = Node(1)
head.next.next = Node(2)

print(head)  # 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> None

def revert(head):
    prev, curr = None, head
    while curr:
        nxt = curr.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = nxt
    return prev

result = revert(head)

print(head) # 0 -> None
print(result) # 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> None
```

Hopefully you can see that nothing is happening automatically. All the modifications to `head` and all other elements of the linked list are direct results of the steps taken in your function.